# touchpad scrolling lost when switching between physical and virtual tty

Tags: terminal, xorg, linux-mint, cinnamon, scrolling

I have setup touchpad scrolling by running the following script in .xsession

```
$ cat ~/bin/enablescrolling 
# enable two finger scroll
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinW=5
synclient EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=48
```

.xsession

```
$ cat ~/.xsession
....
enablescrolling
....
gnome-session --session cinnamon
```

when i switch to /dev/tty6 and come back to /dev/tty8, I lose scrolling. I have captured a few logs. Can someone please point out why this happens?

/var/log/syslog

```
Mar 10 19:15:00 rag-tos-laptop acpid: client 1411[0:0] has disconnected
Mar 10 19:15:00 rag-tos-laptop acpid: client connected from 1411[0:0]
Mar 10 19:15:00 rag-tos-laptop acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

/var/log/ConsoleKit/history

```
1362942899.557 type=SEAT_ACTIVE_SESSION_CHANGED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id=''
1362942900.367 type=SEAT_ACTIVE_SESSION_CHANGED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session1'
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
 18561.016] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-20D7C92BD55EB53CEBBE18F981CB2A77F469F038.xkm
[ 18812.499] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 18814.442] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[ 18814.442] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[ 18814.953] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[ 18819.746] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-20D7C92BD55EB53CEBBE18F981CB2A77F469F038.x
```